# CSP blocking Websocket server connection

Tags: java, angular, websocket, jhipster, content-security-policy

I have a jhipster generated application where I want to add a websocket. Locally everything works, but on the server I'm getting CSP errors. How can this be resolved? I tried adding
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *;">`
to `index.html` but it does not help. Nginx is in front of the application as a proxy.

[image: console errors]

Comment: Did you inspect the csp in browser tools to check your changes are applied?

Comment: Yes, they are all applied.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot, the CSP is set in java not in index.html, this is why your change had no impact.

If you look at SecurityConfiguration.java in your generated project, you'll see this line:

```java
.contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
```

It means that the CSP is directly copied from application properties under `jhipster.security.content-security-policy` key.

So, just edit application.yml to change it.

Comment: I have this line and it's still not working.
```.contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:")```